# Is it possible to detect and launch app A if present, if not then B, if neither are present redirect to store?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to have some kind of prioritized app launch from a browser on android. Goal would be to :
1. launch app A if present
2. If not, but app B is present launch app B
3. If neither : redirect to app A in google play store

Thanks.

Comment: if neither of them is installed on what basis you will check it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: Thanks guys, but as I wrote I'd like those to be launched from a browser.

Comment: No, you cannot do this from a browser, unless you have developed that browser app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to open an application from it's package name

```
    public void runApp(String appName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    for ( ResolveInfo info : getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0) ) {
        if ( info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).equals(appName) ) {
            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
            startActivity(launchIntent);
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Application not found!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote ("from a browser") I'd like to launch it from a browser.

Comment: @Skrew : Sorry for missing the browser but I think Intents don't work on browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. First of all make you app browsable via intent.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="yourapp.com" android:path="/get/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now you can go to this app directly from browser.
Add a landing page with simple script like

```
<script>
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) ) {    
        // redirect to the Play store    
    } else if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ) {    
        // redirect IOS store    
    }
</script>
```

Now you can redirect the user to app if it is installed or in you case now to another app then to the playstore.

```
<a href="http://yourapp.com/get/"/>
```

More details are [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/web-to-app-interoperability-launch-your-android-app-from-the-web/).